# Multiprocessing have session for each worker kept open

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing

I'm using selenium to create a chrome driver, get a link and then extract some information.

I want to cycle through a list of similar pages in a website. I tried using `pool.map(run_func, website_list)` to split the work into separate processes, but using this method each worker gets one element at a time and the `webdriver.Chrome()` will have to be called inside `run_func`.

Is there a simple way to assign a instance of `webdriver.Chrome()` to each worker that remains open, instead of having to open and close it inside the function?

The code looks something like this:

```
def run_func(elem):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path='./chromedriver')
    searcher(driver, elem) # Some other function that does stuff on the website
    driver.close()

def thread_cycle():
    pool = Pool(processes = 10)
    pool.map(run_func, website_list)

def main():
    thread_cycle()
```

Comment: first I thought: if you would use `threading` instead `multiprocessing` then you could use one Chrome for all `threads` because they share memory. But then I released that if you will run two `driver.get()` at the same time then you will have conflict because second url will replace first url and it couldn't get item from first url. It would need to run every url in separated tab.

Comment: `multiprocessing` can send data to other processes but it can't send running object like `webdriver`.

Comment: @furas But is there a way maybe I can open a process and just run 1/N elements with the same process? Like if I have a list of 1000 elements pass 100 to each of the 10 processes, run the driver at the start and leave it open?
So I would have always the same 10x webdrivers running, one for each process.

Comment: you can always convert your list to list with sublists `[ [10urls] , [10urls] , ...]` and then every process will get `10 urls`. Eventually you should run processes which start `Chrome` and next they use `while` loop to get url from main process using `queue`, process it, and repeat it for next url from `queue`.

Comment: True, that is one simple way of doing it.